# Installing a bower package to Laravel 5.4 app

Tags: node.js, laravel, bower

I need to use a front-end package in my Laravel 5.4 application. I spend already 2 hours of googling and reading but I can't find a real solution how to accomplish using that package in my project.
Can please someone explain how it works and how can I achieve it ?
The package is here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-record
So, I installed nodejs and npm to my Ubuntu 16.04
I installed bower globally, then locally in my project. I installed that package using bower, so now I have a bower_components folder in my project. What I have to do next to make it public, to can use this funtions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a custom location for bower packages by adding a [`.bowerrc`](https://bower.io/docs/config/) json file in the root of your project and add a `directory` property to it.

Like so:

```
{ 
    "directory": "public/libraries" 
}
```

Comment: At what stage I have to do it? I already had a bower_components folder in my root directory.
If I will create this file, how can I update it all?
After that I will can use it in my project?
What are the exactly steps to achieve installing and using of a package?

Comment: You can remove the `bower_components` folder, add this config file and run `bower install` again.

Comment: I still have an issue.
In demo of the package developers include files like that : 
<link href="../node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../dist/css/videojs.record.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="../node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/recordrtc/RecordRTC.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/webrtc-adapter/out/adapter.js"></script>

  <script src="../dist/videojs.record.js"></script>


But most of this files I can't find in this folders.

Comment: For example, the first href 
video.js/dist/video-js.min.css
In my copied directory I have that path only : 
/public/libraries/video.js/src/css/video-js.scss

How can I deal with it?